# how to make text field that to accept only 4 digit or numbers in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have an app in which I want to enter a numeric value in `UITextField`. But I want to allow only 4 digits to be entered. So **1234** would be valid but **12345** cannot be entered. Any idea how how I can modify this to accept only a numeric value limited to **4** digits?

Comment: There's a 4-digit code input text field called [CodeInputView](https://github.com/acani/CodeInputView) written in Swift.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *currentString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    int length = [currentString length];
    if (length > 4) {
       return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: +1, though you should really make sure that the replacement string only has numbers. It's not enough to use a numeric keypad, what if the user copies and pastes text?

Comment: @Abizern : Yes, you are right. But, OP has already mentioned in his Question that he managed "to accept only number value", what he/she needs is to restrict user to enter 4 digits only.

Comment: It's also for the OP's benefit. Maybe he/she didn't think that people could add text from the clipboard.

Comment: to work this, please tell OP that you should have textField delegate. Else this would not work. I bet OP don't know this.

Comment: You don't need to use an extra variable for `length` or the string variable `currentString`. Simply replace your `if` statement's condition to `[textField stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string].length`.

Answer (score 4):

> **Swift 3.0 Xcode 8.3.3...**

First `UITextField` set the delegate and then put this code...

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let textstring = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    let length = textstring.characters.count
    if length > 4 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

> **Objective C Code...**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
      {
        NSString *textstring = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        int length = [textstring length];
        if (length > 4) {
           return NO;
        }
            return YES;
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code helped me in setting constraint that only 2 digit and 4 digit in textfield as input. After entering two digit focus automatically move to next textfield.

[image: Screenshot]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

   // Set an action on EditingChanged event of textfield
  txtCardDetails3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VerifyCardViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
}

func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){

  let text = textField.text

   if textField.tag == 101 { // Set tag to textfield (if multiple) during design time
      if text?.utf16.count==2 {
        txtCardDetails4.becomeFirstResponder() // Move to next text field
       }
   }
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
   textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}


//User can enter two digits in textfield with tag 101 and four digits in textfield with tag 102
  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      if let text = textField.text {

        let newStr = (text as NSString)
                .stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
            if newStr.isEmpty {
                return true
            }
            let intvalue = Int(newStr)

            if textField.tag == 101 { print("101")
                 return (intvalue >= 0 && intvalue <= 99) ? true : false
            }
            else if textField.tag == 102 { print("102")
                 return (intvalue >= 0 && intvalue <= 9999) ? true : false
            }

        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited :**

First change your textFiled's keyBoard type `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`, so your keyboard has only numeric/digit.

And give **tag** of your `UITextField` that you want to apply it ***(enter only 4 digit number)*** such like

```
textField.tag = 101; /// this is for, if you have multiple textFiled then it recognize that which textFiled have limit of 4 number ;
```

And use following method's of code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField.tag != 101)
      return YES;

    if(string.length == 0)
      return YES;

    if(textField.text.length == 4)
        return NO;

    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumberSet].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This will prevent deletion once the string has reached four characters. It will also allow you to paste a larger number in if the text is less than 4 characters long.

Comment: what do you mean " prevent deletion once" ?please explain me ?

Comment: Add 4 numbers, now try to delete any of the numbers. Because the text is already 4 characters long you can't make any changes.

Comment: @Abizern - try with my edited answer i put this code in my demo project it works very well for me.. thanks :)

Comment: I'd try and avoid tags as well. rather than some arbitrary number, I'd have an IBOutlet to that textfield and compare it against that.

Comment: @Abizern - i put tag because if you have more then one textFiled then it is better to us for apply this restriction on specific textFiled which has specific **`tag`**

Comment: No. IMHO, it's better to compare against an IBOutlet directly. Tags are better used when you have no control over the UIElements until runtime.

Comment: @Abizern - if i created textFiled programmatically then ?? and thanks for improve my knowledge :)

Comment: If you create the text field programatically than you already have a reference to it. What's the point of adding a tag?

Comment: @Abizern - if i have to created 5 textFiled locally in viewDidload then how can i recognize that which textFiled have limit of 4 number ?

Comment: Presumably you create them something like: `UITextField *textField = [UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`. So now you have a `textField`. Store this as a property and compare against this rather than giving it a tag and checking it. And, if you are putting text in textfield, you are going to need to get it out; so you are going to have to have a textfield reference anyway.

Comment: @Abizern ok, if i created 4 textFiled (as like your above comment `UITextField *textField = [UIText.....`) in `viewDidLoad` method name is **txt1, txt2, txt3 and txt4.** i would like to apply limitation of entry on **txt2** then then how can i get **txt2** in delegate method ??

Comment: In the delegate method: `if(textfield == txt1) {...` etc.

Comment: @Abizern - i can not use as you write because i declare textField in local `(viewDidLoad)` method so how can i get **txt1** ?? (if i declare textFiled in .h file then i able to write `if(textfield == self.txt1) {... `).. without use `self` i can not access **txt1** :( Thanks :0